# Get multiple answers from prolog predicate

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Suppose I have a predicate that sometimes gives me multiple outputs. Like this -

```
foo(Number, Out) :- Number < 10, Out = less_than_ten.
foo(Number, Out) :- Number > 0, Out = more_than_zero.
```

How might I get hold of all the values for `Out` that `foo` gives in another predicate, bearing in mind it can sometimes give one and sometimes give multiple (e.g. in a list)?

Edit - not quite sure the answers I've got answer my question so I'll be more specific. Taking the above predicate, I could run the query `foo(5, Out).` This satisfies both rules, so if I run it in SWI-prolog I'll get this -

```
?- foo(5, Out).
Out = less_than_ten
```

Then I can enter a semi-colon to get prolog to backtrack and look for the other solution -

```
?- foo(5, Out).
Out = less_than_ten ;
Out = more_than_zero.
```

So if I was executing this predicate within another, how do I get all the valid values for Out, given Number = 5?

Answer (score 3):

If you are only considering integers, you can opt to use CLP(FD). Then your predicate foo might look something like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

foo(Nums) :-
   Nums ins 1..9.     % the numbers in the list Nums are 0 < X < 10
```

You can use this predicate to test if a list of numbers is in your desired range:

```
   ?- foo([1,2,3,4,5]).
yes
   ?- foo([0,1,2,3,4,5]).
no
   ?- foo([1,2,3,4,5,10]).
no
```

If you want to use it to generate lists of integers in that range, you have make sure, that `Nums` is a list in order to avoid an instantiation error. You can do that by prefixing a goal length/2 in your query:

```
   ?- length(Nums,_), foo(Nums).
Nums = [] ? ;          % <- no number
Nums = [_A],           % <- one number
_A in 1..9 ? ;
Nums = [_A,_B],        % <- two numbers
_A in 1..9,
_B in 1..9 ? ;
Nums = [_A,_B,_C],     % <- three numbers
_A in 1..9,
_B in 1..9,
_C in 1..9 ?
.
.
.
```

These answers consist of residual goals (see the [CLP(FD) documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for details). If you want to see actual numbers, you have to add a goal to label the list:

```
   ?- length(Nums,_), foo(Nums), label(Nums).
Nums = [] ? ;
Nums = [1] ? ;
Nums = [2] ? ;
Nums = [3] ? ;
.
.
.
Nums = [1,1] ? ;
Nums = [1,2] ? ;
Nums = [1,3] ? ;
.
.
.
Nums = [9,9] ? ;
Nums = [1,1,1] ? ;
Nums = [1,1,2] ? ;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the predicate that answers this question. Prolog has a built in predicate `bagof(Template, Goal, Bag)`, which unifies the `Template` argument of the `Goal` predicate with the `Bag` argument (not sure that's the correct prolog lingo!). So in the example in the question, use `bagof(Out, foo(5, Out), Outputs).`, and this will unify a list of the solutions for `Out` with `Outputs`. Running the query in SWI-prolog:

```
4 ?- bagof(Out, foo(5, Out), Outputs).
Outputs = [less_than_ten, more_than_zero].
```

[A useful guide for different ways to find all solutions to a goal.](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)